# Is loading a blank image faster than multiple if statements?

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement, getelementbyid

My webpage uses a lot (1000+) gifs and displays different gifs using 'if' and 'getElementbyId', would it run quicker if I dropped the if(map(x,y)!=0){... to change the scr and just used a gif which was transparent?

Googled to heck but it's a hard question to word, if a same/similar has been posted please point me there.

Many Thanks

Comment: Transparency is a surprisingly expensive graphical operation. The real question you should ask yourself is why are you using 1000 GIFs? There is almost never (hell, never) a reason that you need 1000 GIFs loaded into the DOM at the same time. If your site really needs 1000 different GIF images, use server side logic to dictate which ones are sent to the client.

Comment: I've a simple suggestion for you - Use `Sprites` technology in this case, Read the answer.

Comment: Thaqnks Chris and Deepak, Chris the gifs build a 'very poor' 3d image of a game map, turning, moving etc needs a reload of the images. Deepak, I think the sprite option is a no go because I want to be cross format and these are large gifs

Comment: Just being curious, How you will now resolve your problem

Comment: I think that if an 'if(map(x,y).. is the same as loading and resizing a blank gif then I'll suffer in silence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you said about getElementById which is a part of **javascript** - A client side scripting language, so that is not a big reason to be worried about.

- You said **1000+** `.gif` images.
- Use concept of `Sprites` in this case
- This will allow you to download all your images in one go.
- This will also reduce some of downloading burden from your server.

To work with sprite technology, Visit this [link](http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/), I believe this is what you need.

Comment: I've never seen such an error in this case you can visit http://spritegen.website-performance.org/ , I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object Pool with [Images](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) and load them on the initialization step. Load them in batches and extend pool with new images if required.

While loading images show spinner. It will be loaded long for a first time, after that a browser will put them in cache.

If you have an opportunity to combine different little images in one (sprite), do it! because it is faster to load one big image, then a lot of little.

Comment: Thanks Warlock, I think a combination of the two is going to be the answer - finding sprite resizing a pain though when you want crossbrowser compatibility